# Hazelcast streams can't de-serialize string

Tags: hazelcast

Hazelcast 3.9.1, Jet 0.5.1

I have a StreamSerializer which calls ObjectDataInput.readObject(clazz)
It seems that the default java de-serializer doesn't implement an interface required by jet: TypedStreamDeserializer

```
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: StreamSerializerAdapter{serializer=com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ConstantSerializers$StringSerializer@3a1efa48} is not implementing the interface com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.TypedStreamDeserializer interface. Please implement this interface to deserialize for class class java.lang.String
   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:55) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:288) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:576) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
   at com.ttcore.caching.distributed.serial.CustomSerializers$HZTypedPropertiesSerializer.read(CustomSerializers.java:304) ~[classes/:?]
   at com.ttcore.caching.distributed.serial.CustomSerializers$HZTypedPropertiesSerializer.read(CustomSerializers.java:322) ~[classes/:?]
   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:60) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:288) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:576) ~[hazelcast-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
   at com.ttcore.caching.distributed.serial.CustomSerializers$HZAccountSerializer.read(CustomSerializers.java:85) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: The reason I am calling this as 'readObject' vs readUTF or some equivalent is that this is a custom Serializer of a heterogeneous map

Comment: Why don't you use `readObject()` (without the class parameter?). That one works. Btw, the problem is not jet-related.

Comment: I suppose this works. I just knew the type so figured that was the proper methodology.

Comment: To me it seems like a bug of Hazelcast.

Comment: This is not a bug. 
`readObject(clazz)` is intended for a specific use case. Probably not applicable to your scenario. `readObject` without class parameter should be used if you write with `writeObject` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sancar answered the question in the comments:

> This is not a bug. readObject(clazz) is intended for a specific use case. Probably not applicable to your scenario. readObject without class parameter should be used if you write with writeObject . – sancar